# GMAT Python API No Convergence

Tags: python, gmat, api

I’m currently using the GMAT Python API in order to set and run my GMAT scripts, but am running into a problem where my scripts do not converge based on certain inputs.
Is there a way in the Python API to exit if the script doesn’t converge? I have read over all the API documentation I can find and the closest I can find is the `gmat.GetSummary()` command, but it only gives info, not whether or not the convergence fails at any point.

Answer (score 3):

Update - Found the solution in a roundabout way. Using a report file, you can report the value of 'GetConvergence'. Then from the Python API you can read this value and use it to flag whether or not the targeting was succesful.